# Pregmatch image url with php from meta tag in instagram header

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, instagram

I am trying to scrape an image url from an Instagram url using php. The image url seems to be be contained in a meta tag at the top of the page like so:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://distilleryimage10.ak.instagram.com/9e4360c6220411e38abf22000a1f9bf5_7.jpg" />
```

From this I would like to return the content part e.g. http://distilleryimage10.ak.instagram.com/9e4360c6220411e38abf22000a1f9bf5_7.jpg

I need to do this for mutiple images so I need to extract this image even if the url changes.

The code I have so far is

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://instagram.com/p/efH-NVOTAy/#');
preg_match("/og:image/", $page, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This prints Array ( [0] => og:image )

This works in as far as it matches 'og:image' and confirms to me it can find this string in the data returned from file_get_contents but I'm not sure how to make the leap to returning the url from this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/og:image"\s*content="([^"]+)"/
```

This looks for `og:image` and then looks for `content` after it, if it found one then it captures the value *(whatever inside double quotes `"`)* into capturing group 1.

So you should receive an array of matches with two elements, the second one being the URL.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uZ7vP3)

**WARNING:** Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML in general, always use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: You show him how to do it, then you tell him not to do it. Wonderful.

Comment: This gives me this error Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home5/bqdevcom/public_html/ssopledge/twitterSearch.php on line 34

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home5/bqdevcom/public_html/ssopledge/twitterSearch.php on line 34

Comment: @pguardiario It sounds weird when you look at it like that :)

Comment: @BenPaton Don't use double quotes `"` to quote the string in `preg_match` or you will have to escape them inside the regex. Use single quotes `'` instead.

Comment: Thanks yes oops, I just figured that out it works when I wrap it in single quotes. Thanks for your help.